# Handling SIGALRM in two different ways

Tags: signals, ipc

How can we handle 2 different alarms sent by `alarm()`??

For example if I have `A=5` and `B=10`, how can I say to my program to do an action after `A` seconds and a different one after `B` seconds without using `sleep()`??

My main purpose with this question it's to understand how can we handle 2 different alarms in the same program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle them one at a time. First, set an alarm for `A=5` seconds. After it fires, do the required task, then set up another alarm for `B-A = 10-5 = 5` seconds. After it fires, do the other task.

Or in general, save the timed tasks in a sorted list, and make it so that there's always an alarm programmed for the time remaining to the first task to be done.

Even more generally, you're probably doing something else in the meanwhile, so you may have some sort of an event loop. In that case, you'd use a timeout in the event loop (the `select()` call perhaps) instead of `alarm()`, and do the timed task from the main program. That way it doesn't matter if the alarm fires right in the middle of doing something else and no concurrent processing to mess things up.